# How to send values form setOnValueChangedListener to onCreate()?

Tags: java, android

This is my dialog and i want to send the Tmin and Thr to on create  or other public. this app is i want to set the time and show on the mainactivy but now i don't know how to send the value to the other public can anyone help me

```
private String Tmin;
private String Thr;


public void set_dialog(View v){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder( this );
    View row = getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.settime,null );
    final TextView  textView=(TextView)row.findViewById( R.id.textView10 ) ;
    final TextView  textView1=(TextView)row.findViewById( R.id.textView8 ) ;
    NumberPicker numPicker=(NumberPicker)row.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
    numPicker.setMaxValue(12);
    numPicker.setMinValue(0);
    numPicker.setValue(1);
    NumberPicker numPickerhr=(NumberPicker)row.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
    numPickerhr.setMaxValue(59);
    numPickerhr.setMinValue(0);
    numPickerhr.setValue(1);

    numPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener (){
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker view, int oldValue, int newValue) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pick number is " + String.valueOf(newValue), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //textView.setText( String.valueOf(newValue));
            Tmin = String.valueOf(newValue);
            textView.setText(Tmin);
        }
    });
    numPickerhr.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener (){
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker view, int oldValue, int newValue) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pick number is " + String.valueOf(newValue), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Thr = String.valueOf(newValue);
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setView( row );

    /*alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //按下按鈕時顯示快顯

        }
    });*/
    AlertDialog dialog=alertDialog.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you will have one more button in your alertDialog, example `OK` button. Once `OK` button is clicked, return these two values to Main Activity.

```
 builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           //get text to string
           String text = "Min : "+TMin+"Thr : "+Thr;
           textView_main.setText(text);  
        }
 });
```

Declare textView named `textView_main` for your Main Activity.